# CurrentPerson.getCover().getCoverPhoto().geturl() throws exception

Tags: android, google-plus

When i tried to get the cover photo of the current logged in person using `currentPerson.getCover().getCoverPhoto().geturl();` it throws exception and the `e.getMessage()` is null. I am getting profile picture url in the same method using `currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();` How can I get the cover picture url of the person signed in.

Comment: Do you have the required permissions? Can you see other informations like the person's name?
Also, sometimes if you have no internet connection or your API permissions on Google API Console aren't properly configured you can get a null person, check if the person is null.

Comment: Yes I am getting profile picture and display name. and the code to fetch url is inside the if block that checks for null

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: when i tried to log the exception using e.getMessage() it is throwing exception. and I don't know what exception it is throwing at me

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace()`, copy the stacktrace and put it on your question.You can see the error line in the stacktrace. It will apear on the logcat, you know where it is, right?

Comment: i just changed the cover pic  in my google plus profile and now i am getting cover picture.

Comment: You didn't have any cover set? I think there's a default one, so it counts as if there were no cover.